# Setting image upload absolute path?

Tags: uploads

In anticipation of a major upgrade, I moved the webroot from `site_v1` to `site_v2`. The public url for the WP 3.3.1 install is still example.com/ (no change). I did a tar copy from the /site_v1 dir to the new /site_v2 dir.

The WP installation is working well from its new Linux path of /site_v2 instead of site_v1. All pre-existing images continue to work fine etc.

**The Problem** is that when new image files are uploaded using either the flash or classic uploader, the files themselves are put into /site_v1/wp-content/uploads/2012/03 instead of the correct /site_v2/wp-content/uploads/2012/03 location.

How do I change the upload file location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry if you have tried this already, but I go for the simplest answer first ;)

In dashboard, Settings -> Media -> Uploading Files section to set path.